# How to distinguish whether onDestroy will be called after onPause

Tags: android, android-activity, call, lifecycle, ondestroy

Is there any way how to distinguish whether `onDestroy()` will be called after `onPause()`? In may activity I need to do different action when Activity lost focus and when Activity is going down, but even when activity is going down `onPause()` is called before `onDestroy()` I want to do different action in `onPause()` when activity lost focus and when is going down and `onDestroy()` is gonna be called.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes with:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (this.isFinishing()) {
         // WAHT YOU WANT TO DO BEFORE DESTROYING...
    }
}
```

But of course it can't handle if your app crashs ;)